Call to undefined method TestCase::get()
While running the tests I'm getting this error

ReflectionException: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::get()
at vendor/pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel/src/Http.php:189
at tests/Feature/HealthTest.php:8

I tried many things but nothing works. My Unit tests run correctly with no issue. there is no get, post delete request. but my feature tests don't run at all. I tried searching for solution for days and now I'm posting my issue here. Can anyone help me identify the cause and how can I solve it?
Directory Structure

tests

inside tests there are two folders and two files

Pest.php
TestCase.php
Unit (folder)
Features (folder)

Inside feature I have HealthTest.php
in the porject directory I have phpunit.xml
Pest.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Test Case
| The closure you provide to your test functions is always bound to a specific PHPUnit test
| case class. By default, that class is "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase". Of course, you may
| need to change it using the "uses()" function to bind a different classes or traits.
|
*/

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

uses(TestCase::class)->in('Feature');
uses(TestCase::class)->in('Unit');


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Expectations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When you're writing tests, you often need to check that values meet certain conditions. The
| "expect()" function gives you access to a set of "expectations" methods that you can use
| to assert different things. Of course, you may extend the Expectation API at any time.
|
*/

expect()->extend('toBeOne', function () {
    return $this->toBe(1);
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Functions
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While Pest is very powerful out-of-the-box, you may have some testing code specific to your
| project that you don't want to repeat in every file. Here you can also expose helpers as
| global functions to help you to reduce the number of lines of code in your test files.
|
*/

function something()
{
    // ..
}


HealthTest.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

//uses(Tests\TestCase::class);

use function Pest\Laravel\{get};

test('service healthy', function () {
    $response = get('/');
    $response->assertStatus(503);
});


test('pings', function (){
    $res = get('/ping', ['Device-Id'=> '3984732984792420934231']);
    $res->assertStatus(200);
});

phpunit.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         color="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         stopOnFailures="false"
         syntaxCheck="true">
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Middlewares">
            <directory phpVersion="8.3">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Features">
            <directory phpVersion="8.3">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>


laravel/php/pestphp versions??

Laravel : 11.15, PHP : 8.3.6, PestPHP :  2.34.9

I tried many solutions and compared my code with th examples that were present on the internet. I found out two things
at the top of every test file I uncommented the following line
uses(Tests\TestCase::class);

and all the calls to get(), postJson() are preceded by $this->
test('pings', function (){
    $res = $this->get('/ping', ['Device-Id'=> '3984732984792420934231']);
    $res->assertStatus(200);
});

This fixed the issue and now the tests are running
